# ASMX using mono Type Webservice not found

Tags: c#, web-services, mono, asmx

I am trying to start an ASMX webservice using mono and mod_mono in Apache on a CentOS server and I get a 500 error saying Type Webservice not found.

I tried this also on a Ubuntu environment and I get the same error. I tried uninstalling mono, apache and reinstalling them clean a few times, I configured mod_mono but I can't seem to figure out what is causing this.

Here is the whole error message

```
System.Web.HttpException: Type WebService not found.
  at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetTypeFromBin (System.String tname) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.SimpleBuildProvider.LoadTypeFromBin (System.Web.Compilation.BaseCompiler compiler, System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser parser) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.GenericBuildProvider`1[System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser].GetGeneratedType (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults results) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerCacheItem..ctor (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider bp, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults results) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.StoreInCache (System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider bp, System.Reflection.Assembly compiledAssembly, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults results) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String verb, System.String url, System.String filePath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url, Boolean ignoreContextHandler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator3.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: the latest version installed with yum, thank you for your help.

Comment: and what version does yum install? you can check by writing this in the console: `mono --version`

Comment: it outputs this: Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8 (tarball Wed Dec  4 09:32:19 EST 2013)

Comment: alright, that is a **very old** version of mono, you need to upgrade

Comment: thanks for you support, I am trying to update for a few hours now, ran into all sorts of problems. I tried building it from source and after make && make install when I call mono --version I still get 2.10.8... I will keep trying to update. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I recommend you to use packages